# Uncaught TypeError: XXX.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I get this error when following promise example.

```
let p2 = () => { return Promise.resolve("foo"); };

const test1 = () => {
   console.log("Test1 started");
   p2.then((res) => console.log("P2: " + res));
};

test1();
```

Error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: p2.then is not a function
```

Comment: You're not actually calling that function

Comment: better now ...?

Comment: Well 1. not really because that's not the name of the test function and 2. no because you're still not calling the function that returns a promise.

Comment: :) fixing.......

Comment: Why p2 i s not p2.then ?

Comment: and how to solve it in ES6?

Comment: ...by *actually calling p2*?!

Comment: p2().then(/*code*/)

Comment: @P.K. write `p2().then((res) => console.log("P2: " + res));`   instead `p2.then((res) => console.log("P2: " + res));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p2` is a function that returns a promise, `p2()` is the promise, so you need to do

```
p2().then((res) => console.log("P2: " + res));
```

Comment: @P.K. this isn't a promise problem; you'd see the same error if you wrote `const p2= () => ({ foo: () => "bar" });` then `p2.foo()`.